# Finding Critical Values of Function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$f(x)=x^{\frac{5}{11}}\cdot(x-5)^2$$

So far, I have used the product rule and chain rule to get...

$$\left(\frac{5}{11}x^{\frac{-6}{11}}\cdot(x-5)^2\right)+\left(x^{\frac{5}{11}}\cdot(2(x-5))\cdot 1\right)$$

I was wondering if someone could help me with the following steps. I think the fractions keep throwing me off.

Comment: This looks like only one use of the product rule

Comment: Sorry, I meant product rule

Comment: Just testing you ;) So you set the derivative equal to zero?

Comment: I kept trying to factor the x values out first. So leave those alone for now and just set it to zero?

Comment: Yup; you'll be able to cancel easier

Comment: So far, I have (5/11)*(x-5)=-2x^(-1/11)

Is this right so far?

Comment: Oh I see what you did; yes that looks good so far. Although I wouldn've multiplied each side by $x^\frac{6}{11}$ to simplify more

Comment: I'm confused about how to further solve it. I tried dividing out the (x-5) terms to get (x-5) on the left side and then dividing out the x(5/11)/x^(6/11) to get -2x^(-1/11) on the right side

Comment: Both work. So what happens if $x=5$?

Comment: The critical number will equal zero?

Comment: Isn't that what we wanted?

Comment: Yes, but I'm getting an incorrect answer for 5. Is there an additional critical number?

Comment: Should be one more

Comment: I figured the second would be zero, but that is incorrect as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would factor out an $x^{-6/11}$ to get:
$$\left(\frac{5}{11}x^{-6/11}(x-5)^2\right)+\left(x^{5/11}(2(x-5))\right) = x^{-6/11}\left(\frac{5}{11}(x-5)^2+x(2(x-5))\right).$$
Note that factorization is basically division, which can be performed by subtraction of exponents here, so that the $x$ in front of the $2(x-5)$ on the right arose because 
$$x^{5/11}/x^{-6/11} = x^{\frac{5}{11}+\frac{6}{11}}.$$
At this point, you simply have to find the roots of the polynomial on the right.

Comment: This is what I did the first time I attempted this problem, but I keep getting stuck on the polynomial

Comment: @user138002 The easy way to deal with the polynomial is to factor out an $x-5$.  You should get $(x-5) (27 x-25)/11$.

Comment: Okay, so I did that, and I got 0, 5, and 25/27
Is that correct?

Comment: @user138002 I guess you'll be able to tell if you [look at a graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3gw4adzs5y). The critical points will appear as max/mins and, if the graph looks like it's infinitely steep at a point, the derivative is undefined there.

Comment: Thank you for your help! That was the answer